# How to extract a string between two characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Situation:**

I have a column decoded from Hex to varchar where  values look like this:

```
{"something":"example"}
```

**Objective:**

I would like to extract the second word between the quotes.

**What i tried:**

I started with a couple of `substring` and `charindex` functions but my code looks more complicated than it should be.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
            SUBSTRING(
                '{"something":"example"}',
                charindex(':"','{"something":"example"}')+2,
                LEN('{"something":"example"}')-charindex(':"','{"something":"example"}')+2),
            0,
            CHARINDEX('"',SUBSTRING(
                '{"something":"example"}',
                charindex(':"','{"something":"example"}')+2,
                LEN('{"something":"example"}')-charindex(':"','{"something":"example"}')+2))
                )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try with REPLACE to strip all the characters you don't need, then work on just string : string
Or string_split, then REPLACE

Comment: Where that data comes from?

Comment: Newer versions of sql server work well with `json` data, which this is. You could do `SELECT json_value('{"something":"example"}', '$.something')` for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on SQL Server 2016+, you can use `OPENJSON`:

```
SELECT [value]
FROM OPENJSON('{"something":"example"}');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d051a7a7f119edf467cc71a97e4669d1)

So against a table:

```
SELECT [value]
FROM (VALUES('{"something":"example"}'),
            ('{"another":"sample"}'))V(S)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(V.S);
```

This returns:

```
value
-------
example
sample
```

Comment: How do I do this for an entire column though?

Comment: Replace `'{"something":"example"}'` with the column's name.

Comment: iám still geussing about the SQL Server's `CROSS APPLY` real meaning is it like ANSI/ISO SQL standards    `SELECT .... LATERAL JOIN ( SELECT ... )`  ? Which basically makes "co-related" JOIN's possible.

Comment: You *can* use `CROSS APPLY` do perform a lateral join, yes @RaymondNijland. It's also used to call table value functions, `VALUES` clauses, etc, as it doesn't require an `ON`. I'm not familiar with `LATERAL JOIN`, as my expertise is in SQL Server, so I can't say "yes" with any certaincy.